# Understanding the {$WARN XXXX OFF} compiler directive

Tags: freepascal

If I'm trying to indiscriminately silence compiler messages the compiler command line parameter -vmXXXX works perfectly for the whole project. However, if I'm trying to silence messages selectively in the source I have to use the {$WARN XXXX OFF} compiler directive.

The problem is... I am having a really hard time understanding the rules of how that compiler directive is applied. In the example below of 1 program and 2 units, if you uncomment the {$WARN XXXX OFF} command one at a time, what will happen is not what I would expect (the result is written in the comment for each compiler directive).

Is there anyone who can explain exactly how that compiler directive works?

Program:

```
program Project1;
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
uses
 Unit1;
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence neither the unit2 hint nor the unit1 hint
begin
 if convert_it(0)=nil then
  halt(1);
end.
```

First Unit:

```
unit Unit1;
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
interface
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
function convert_it(avalue:longint):pointer;
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
implementation
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
uses
 unit2;
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit1 hint but not the unit2 hint
function convert_it(avalue:longint):pointer;
begin
 result:=pointer(do_it(avalue));
end;

end.
```

Second Unit:

```
unit Unit2;
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
interface
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
function do_it(avalue:longint):longint;
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
implementation
//{$WARN 4055 OFF} // will silence the unit2 hint but not the unit1 hint
function do_it(avalue:longint):longint;
var
 p:pointer;
begin
 p:=pointer(avalue);
 if p=nil then
  result:=avalue+1
 else
  result:=avalue-1;
end;

end.
```

Comment: After the discussion in the answer by BBaz I decided to see if this is a bug and filed a bug report available at: http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=27269 . If this turns out to be working as intended I'll accept BBaz's answer, otherwise we'll have to wait until it's fixed to use this feature or use it while being aware of it's unusual operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse2.html#x7-60001.2):

> Local directives can occur more than once in a unit or program, If
>   they have a command line counterpart, the command line argument is
>   restored as the default for each compiled file. The local directives
>   influence the compiler’s behaviour from the moment they’re encountered
>   until the moment another switch annihilates their behaviour, or the
>   end of the current unit or program is reached.

So the directives you use are valid from their declaration to the end of **a** unit, following the **use** clauses, after what the default value is restored.

For each unit, for each nth directive

- Program

  - 1: the directive is activated, still valid in **unit1** because of the **use**, still valid in **unit2** because of the use. But after **unit2** (end of a unit) the default value is restored, so you got the message in **unit1**.
  - 2: the directive is activated after the use so it has no effect whatever is the unit.
- Unit1

  - 1: the directive is activated, still valid in **unit2** because of the **use**. But after **unit2** (end of a unit) the default value is restored, so you got the message in **unit1**.
  - 2: ditto
  - 3: ditto
  - 4: ditto
  - 5: the directive is only activated for **unit1** implementation section.
- Unit2, all cases: the directive is only activated for **unit2**.

The tricky thing to get here is that it follows the **use**.

Comment: Woah ok I understand what you wrote, it seems to describe exactly what is happening, even the way the directive in the program source file works! But it's soooooo weird and unexpected, and most importantly, it's not like the other local compiler directives, like say, {$DEFINE whatever}, which is a local directive that can be put on the command line, yet if I put it instead of the first {$WARN 4055 OFF} right under the 'program Project1;' line in the program source file will not affect unit1 or unit2 but will affect the entire program source file, even after the 'uses unit1;' line.

Comment: I'm tempted to think it's a bug that this local directive follows the rules you just wrote instead of the same rules as other local compiler directives like {$define], but I have a hard time believing if it was a bug it wouldn't have been detected before considering how many people use free pascal. Maybe I should make an account on freepascal.org and ask if this is working as intended, what do you think?

Comment: @Marladu It's not a bug. It works the same way that the same directive works in Delphi. Different directives have different scope by design. And it can't be a bug if it is *documented behavior*, by definition.

Comment: Well I fired up delphi XE7 and tested this and {$WARN XXXX OFF} does not follow uses clauses, it acts exactly like {$DEFINE}. Also rereading the manual quote extracted by BBaz I don't see where it says any local compiler directive should follow uses clause and end at the end of any unit rather then apply to current source file and no more. I now think BBaz explained perfectly what we're observing but that this isn't how it should be. I'm all out of nerd time for today but when I have some time tomorrow or thursday I'll write something on the freepascal site and report back here when have news.

Comment: You're right it's not said anywhere, and I've myself been quite surprised by the behaviour...the only logical conclusion was that: it follows the uses. But as the hypothesis explains well the different cases so it's quite probable that it's the right answer. Maybe a few cases are missing: the uses clause in the implementation section. To be sure you'd need an answer from someone who knows well the FPC internal design.

Comment: I've filed a bug report and added a note under the question pointing to it. Thanks for your time and explanation BBaz, for some reason I was having trouble figuring out what was going on even with such short code. How about adding a note to your answer that says this is how it currently works but might change in future versions of free pascal so i can accept your answer right away?

Comment: Common Marladu don't go too far with the people kindness. I've helped you to understand the thing. Copy that ? Roger this ?

Comment: Alright, sorry, thanks for your help, answer accepted.